# Select different clients and put it in table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to put differents clients in table string content nom client

that's that i want :

i have a database table client(ID,Name,Age,Telephone,Adresse,Adressemail)
i want to select all different clients and put him  in table :

```
String Nameclient[];
```

this table content all ***Name*** clients from table database client

because i want select all clients in my table.
Can someone help me how can i do this and thank you very much for help

Comment: Do you know how to access the database to execute a SQL query? Are you using any kind of ORM tool? The answer to your question depends on how you are querying the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var results = (from ta in db.Client
                           select new {
                                Name=  ta.Name}).Distinct().ToList();
            string[] Names = new string[results.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
              {
                  Names[i] = results[i].Name;
              }
```